# Phone Gap Iphone development

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am just starting out experimenting with using Phone Gap to create an Iphone app, and in the Get Started guide it says a requirement is Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6).

[Link](http://phonegap.com/start#ios-x4)

I thought it was possible do Phone Gap development on any machine using HTML/CSS/Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Phone Gap can build the app for you in is own server: https://build.phonegap.com/ . With that you don't need a mac to develop your app.

If you need private apps, this feature isn't free.

Comment: Actually.. that's not even really true. You still need access to a Mac at least to begin using PhoneGap Build. See: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds as quoted in the other answer.

Comment: Apple developer certificate are standard certificate. You can create it with other platform but there isn't so simple documentation. You can do that with key tool utility in command line for sample http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html

Answer (score 0):

[PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app stores.](http://phonegap.com/) If the platform is supposed to produce a native iOS app (that can be submitted to AppStore) then you need to have Mac OS because Objective-C is supported on Mac/XCode.

[More from their website](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds):

> The process for completing iOS builds is slightly different than that
>   for other platforms: all iOS builds need to be signed by a developer
>   certificate and a provisioning profile, that is tied to your Apple
>   developer account and the device you wish to test on. This document
>   covers how to set this up.
>
> Note: Since PhoneGap Build uses Apple's standard development process
>   to build applications, you will need to sign up for their developer
>   program to build iOS applications on PhoneGap Build. You will also
>   need a Mac to configure your certificate and provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

actually using phonegap application u can run your application in iPhone , Android & so many Phone application with single code which is written using html-5 ,css , jQuery , javaScript & jQuery mobile.
but if you want to post your application on apple app store then you have to have XCode which can run in only mac os.
so while you are designing or implementation time you not need mac os. all you need is notepad & html 5 supported browser.(for testing) Thats it.